# Xamarin iOS share button

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

How to implement in Xamarin.iOS social sharing like in native development?
[image]

Answer (score 5):

Could do something like this:

```
 public override void ViewDidLoad ()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad ();
            // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
            var button = new UIButton (UIButtonType.RoundedRect) {
                Frame = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds,
                BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red
            };

            button.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) => {
                var item = NSObject.FromObject ("HI");
                var activityItems = new NSObject[] { item };
                UIActivity[] applicationActivities = null;

                var activityController = new UIActivityViewController (activityItems, applicationActivities);

                PresentViewController (activityController, true, null);
            };

            Add (button);
        }
```

The items you share have to be derived from NSObjects.

And you can exclude activities by setting `ExcludedActivityTypes` on the `UIActivityViewController`

With the code above I get this in the simulator:
[image: Simulator]

Comment: yep, already implemented this for testing, but question was about the same share view as on attached pic, not just list of social networks, it looks pretty poor

Comment: So just Mail, Twitter, Read list & Copy?

Comment: I have attached what I see when I run the simulator, they look the same too me but maybe I'm missing something. What iOS version are you building on? Are you able to post your test implementation code?

Comment: hi! thanks a lot for the answer, yep now it's really looks like what I need, just was confused by that applicationActivities array. But I don't see any of my social networks (twitter or fb), I even signed in facebook in settings, but still nothing

Answer (score 2):

Now in projects I use this component:

https://components.xamarin.com/view/facebook-sdk

and in button's TouchUpInside I invoke a method like this:

```
    void Share(string sharingUrl)
    {
        var content = new ShareLinkContent();
        content.SetContentUrl(new NSUrl(sharingUrl));

        var shareDialog = new FacebookShareDialog
                              {
                                  FromViewController = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController,
                                  Mode = ShareDialogMode.Native
                              };
        shareDialog.SetShareContent(content);
        shareDialog.Show();
    }
```

where FacebookShareDialog is a derived class

```
public class FacebookShareDialog : ShareDialog
{
    public FacebookShareDialog()
        : base(NSObjectFlag.Empty)
    {
    }
}
```

It works better than just add a FacebookShareButton due to the fact you can choose how it shares - Native or ShareSheet dialogs modes are really more useful than just opening share dialog in browser.

Comment: well, not just facebook sign in required for me, it's also twitter and vk.com, I hope there is more simple solution

Comment: Well, for Twitter we was writing our own binding of TwitterKit. Fortunately we don't need Vkontakte right now.
But in common it's a harder but more correct flow 'cause many users don't log in into social networks in browser, only in apps.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this component: https://components.xamarin.com/view/xamarin.social

Comment: it's awfully outdated, since facebook changed their api

Comment: oh sorry about that, my bad

Answer (score 0):

the best way is to use

https://github.com/jguertl/SharePlugin

then after installing the package you can call the command or event just like that :

```
public Command Share {
            get { 
                return new Command ((parameter) => {
                    CrossShare.Current.Share(((Joke)parameter).JokeTxt,"title");
                });
            }
        }
```

Comment: do nothing : /

i have this inside button touch:

`CrossShare.Current.Share("message","title");`