# How to post images and videos on Instagram using Xamarin. iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

How can I post images on Instagram similar to `SLComposeViewController` using c# in a Xamarin.iOS application.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can share extra text like in SLComposeViewController with Instagram or Facebook. 
Have a look [here](http://developers.instagram.com/post/125972775561/removing-pre-filled-captions-from-mobile-sharing)

Might be best with a `UIActivityViewController` and add the image to activityItems like in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/32783758/1107580

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways at the moment how can you share pictures from your app to Instagram:

1. Save the picture to your Camera gallery. Open Instagram app using URL **@"instagram://camera"**. It opens Instagram app directly whit pictures sorted by the date of creation and yours one will be the first.
2. Open action sheet using **UIDocumentInteractionController**. After user selects Import in Instagram, the Instagram's share flow starting with the cropping will pop out.

Here is the code in Xamarin for the second option:

```
UIImage imageToUse = _your_ui_image_instance;
NSString documentDirectory = (new NSString(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal)));
string saveImagePath = documentDirectory.AppendPathComponent(new NSString(@"Image.ig"));
NSData imageData = imageToUse.AsPNG();
imageData.Save(saveImagePath, true);
NSUrl imageURL = NSUrl.FromFilename(saveImagePath);

DocumentController = new UIDocumentInteractionController();
DocumentController.Url = imageURL;
DocumentController.Uti = "com.instagram.photo";

DocumentController.PresentOpenInMenu(new RectangleF(1, 1, 1, 1), View, true);
```

Remember to declare DocumentController as a class' field instead of a local property (error will be arisen once PresentOpenInMenu will be executed for losing the UIDocumentInteractionController too early).

You can alternatively show much fewer apps in the action sheet using uti **com.instagram.exclusivegram** and extension **.igo**.

Comment: What is the View variable?

Comment: @gianis6 View is the attribute of your screen - UIViewController.